# Identifying specs of speaker from Chrysler Concorde

Tags: audio, chrysler, speakers

The speaker in the driver's side door of a Chrysler Concorde went bad. I removed the speaker and would like to replace *only* the one speaker. What specs should I be looking for? Here are pictures of the speaker:

[image]

[image]

If you need a better picture of the connector, I will do my best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you need to know is the impedance (measured in ohms) of the speaker - you might have to hunt for the model number if it doesn't mention it anywhere. Look for a number with a Greek Omega after it - likely to be somewhere around 4 or 8...

The new speaker will have to have the same impedance as the one you're removing, to balance the one on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Diameter and depth and impedance.  Might as well do both since speakers are almost always sold in pairs.  If you go to crutchfield or bestbuy or just about any website that sells car speakers, they should have a lookup tool for the size speaker you need.

Since you just want to replace one, you might want to go to the junkyard and look for the same or similar model car.